# Test if element is present

Tags: c#, powershell, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I've added Selenium WebDriver to the Powershell and create WebDriver instance:

```
Add-Type -path C:\Windows\net40\WebDriver.dll
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver
$driver.Url = "https://www.google.com"
```

Now I want to find input field:

```
$singleRecord = ($driver.FindElementByCssSelector("input.gbqfif"))
```

I found several examples how to "Test if element is present" in C#:

[Selenium WebDriver - Test if element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present)

[Selenium c# Webdriver: Wait Until Element is Present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present)

There is also guide [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits):

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
    });
```

but I cannot create something similar in Powershell, and almost all my tests fails because it takes time for page to load elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this API but if you're having problems getting it to work in PowerShell but it works in C#, then just create C# wrappers around the functionality you need that you can access from PowerShell.  You can do this fairly easily with the `Add-Type` command. From the first example in its doc page:

```
$source = @"
public class BasicTest { 
    public static int Add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b);
    }  
    public int Multiply(int a, int b) {
        return (a * b);
    }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source

[BasicTest]::Add(4, 3)
$basicTestObject = New-Object BasicTest
$basicTestObject.Multiply(5, 2)
```

As you find C# code for this API that does work, you can plop it into a C# wrapper class that you can call from PowerShell.  The key is to avoid features PowerShell can't handle like C# static extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

The only really safe way is:

```
    static bool isElementPresent(dynamic element, By by)
    {
        try
        {
            element.FindElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This method accept both, an *IWebDriver* or an *IWebElement*, as a starting point for *FindElement()*.

And so you can us it on a *LINQ* Query:

`_infodeskSectionContracts = from contract in
    _infodeskSection.FindElements(By.CssSelector(_base + " * ul.list.type-itemlist li"))
        select new Contract
            {
                element = contract.FindElement(By.TagName("a")),
                label = contract.FindElement(By.TagName("h4")).Text,
                contractNumber = (isElementPresent(contract, By.TagName("p")) ? contract.FindElement(By.TagName("p")).Text : "0000")
            };`