# Selenium: how to find textfield element is present or not present then do something with it?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<input id="password" name="password" maxlength="500" size="18" autocomplete="off" type="password">

<input id="passcode" name="password" maxlength="6" size="18" autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

I want to find if password textfield exist then enter "myPassword" otherwise
if passcode textfield exist then enter "myPassCode" else throw exception.

```
if input id "password" exist then enter "mytext" otherwise
else if input id "passcode" exist then enter  "myPassCode"
else throw exception (missing password,passcode text fields)
```

Must be a better way to do it then this???? (bad code) :(

```
        try

        {

            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("myPassword");

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            try

            {

                driver.FindElement(By.Id("passcode")).SendKeys("myPassCode");

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {



            }

        }
```

Comment: You should check element exist first. E.g.: driver.FindElements(), then check size(), if size() > 0 -> element exists -> sendKeys

Comment: It will throw an exception, -this will throw an exception---->                 var passwordFieldElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));

Comment: I used FindElements (with s in the end) :)

Comment: Yep, I just found that answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `List<IWebElement> passwordElements = driver.FindElements(By.Id("password"))`.  If passwordElements has more than 0 items in it, you can use it.  If none were found you can check your other type, and then call `SendKeys` appropriately.

Comment: Maybe this IWebElement passwordElements = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));?

Comment: I don't think so.  If I remember correctly, `FindElement` will throw `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : The element could not be found` when it doesn't find what it expects.  `FindElements` will try to find some, and return an empty `List<IWebElement>` if none are found.  I don't have Visual Studio in front of me where I can look at the tests I've written that use this.  I'll try to update once I'm in the office tomorrow morning.

Comment: this throws an exception :( var passwordFieldElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));

Comment: yes.. I'm saying call `FindElements` NOT `FindElement`.  You need to call the one with 's' on the end that will return the collection type.

Comment: Yep, I just found that answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present thanks :)