# i want to handle exception by writing a method in selenium webdriver saying that if the element is present or not

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage which i'm trying to automate using selenium webdriver...will give a short description abt d webpage, when i enter a valid id in the inputbox and clicks on search button..i will get the results of the input provided...if i give an invalid input..it will give "No records Found!" message..i want to handle both the cases by writing isElementPresent(By by) method...can anyone help on this ?? how to write a method including syntax...or anyone please post the sample method with a code example...sooner response is much appreciated !!

Comment: I am afraid but this is not a good place to ask this kind of question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present

Answer (score 1):

I put together a code snippet in another question very recently that does this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29149283/4611801

```
public boolean elementExists(By selector)
{
    try
    {
        driver.findElement(selector)
        return true;
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```