# Selenium Tests Find if Display is None

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I find out if the element display is none or not?

Currently, I am using the `IWebElement GetAttribute("Style")` method to get the style which returns everything in the style property. I can then parse through the string and find `display:none`.

I am just wondering if there is an easier and cleaner way?

Answer (score 3):

You can also execute javascript and get the `.style.display` value of an element:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string display = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].style.display;", element);
```

---

If you just want to test an element's visibility - then don't reinvent the wheel and let the webdriver handle it. There is [`Displayed`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Displayed.htm) property:

```
element.Displayed
```

FYI, behind `Displayed` webdriver has a quite complicated logic built-in, see:

- [Element Displayedness](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#element-displayedness)

Comment: Thanks! But when you say visibility don't you mean if the element is present in the DOM or not. I am usually checking for display:none where the element is always in the DOM but with no display.

Comment: @johndoe when I speak about visibility, I refer to what is `perceptually visible to the human eye`. To check if element is present, one would usually check if selenium can find an element (no exception is thrown), or use `FindElements` and check the size of the result to be more than 0. (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present)

Comment: @johndoe good, see if the answer deserves to be accepted. Thanks.