# I cannot navigate to else part of my selenium code ,always getting failure

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, automation

Please see my below code:

My `if` part of code  is running successfully but my `else` part is not working.
The code gets skipped and is showing failure.

```
 if (driver.findElement(By.id("error_explanation")).isDisplayed() == true) {
     driver.findElement(By.id("user_email")).clear();
     driver.findElement(By.id("user_email")).sendKeys("soumya50@toobler.com");
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).sendKeys("password");
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.findElement(By.id("user_current_password")).sendKeys("password");
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("LOGOUT")).click();
 } else

 {
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("REQUEST A PERMIT")).click();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
```

Getting error as below:-

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"error_explanation"}

Comment: Please describe what is wrong in your else-branch or what kind of help do you need. Thank you.

Comment: my TestNG result is showing as

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"error_explanation"}... please help me how to over come this

Comment: Please update the question and post full error log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver - Test if element is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because when the element is not visible... it is apparently not on the page at all. You first need to check to see if the element exists, then see if it's visible.

The proper way to check if an element exists according to the [Selenium docs](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is to use `.findElements()` and check for an empty `List`. I combined the `.isEmpty()` check with the `.isDisplayed()` check in your existing `if`. This should work now.

```
List<WebElement> errorExplanation = driver.findElements(By.id("error_explanation"));
if (!errorExplanation.isEmpty() && errorExplanation.get(0).isDisplayed())
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("user_email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("user_email")).sendKeys("soumya50@toobler.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("user_current_password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("LOGOUT")).click();
}
else
{
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("REQUEST A PERMIT")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: java.util.List<WebElement> errorExplanation = driver.findElements(By.id("error_explanation"));  ::; than kyou :)

Answer (score 3):

In Selenium you should not use `driver.findElement` to check if an element exists or not. 
Use `driver.findElements` instead. It returns a list of WebElement.
You can then check if the list is empty or not.

Please view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :-

1st way:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("URL");
    By element=By.id("error_explanation"));

    Boolean isPresent =isElementPresent(element);

    System.out.println(isPresent);

    if(isPresent==true)
    {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No");
    }

}


public boolean isElementPresent(By locatorKey) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(locatorKey);
        return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

2nd way:-

```
    By element=By.id("error_explanation"));

    Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(element).size() > 0;

    System.out.println(isPresent);

    if(isPresent==true)
    {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new function as below,

```
public boolean findElementById(String id)
{
        try {
        webDriver.findElement(By.id(id));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

check if condition as below in your code:

```
 if (findElementById("error_explanation")) {
  .....
 }else {
  .....
 }
```