# Selenium Testing : If element is not present then exception is not handled by Exception of type NoSuchElementException in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

If any element doesnot exists in Selenium Testing, then I am unable to handle it. I have tried this code.

```
    public static bool IsElementPresent(IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It shows timeout exception takes too much time more than 1 min and finally handled by main Exception class, but my automation testing stops, And I dont want to stop my testing.

I have tried this code snippet also.

```
public bool IsElementPresent(IWebDriver driver, By by, TimeSpan? timeSpan)
{
    bool isElementPresent = false;
    try
    {
        if (timeSpan == null)
        {                    
            timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        }
        var driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, (TimeSpan)timeSpan);                       
        driverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException));
        isElementPresent=driverWait.Until(x => x.FindElements(by).Any());
        return isElementPresent;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException nex) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What should I do so that in small span of time it returns true or false.

Comment: I have tried this too, not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present

Comment: Do you have implicitWait() set somewhere? What is it set to?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be something like

```
return driver.FindElements(by).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the Displayed property. I use the page object model with pre-determined IWebElements in the example below:

```
    public bool IsPageObjectPresent(IWebElement PageObject)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PageObject.Displayed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element is displayed");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element present but not visible");
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element not present");
            return false;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stale element present");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its also not working, when element is not present, Time Out Exception, I want to check for element present or not present with maximum of 10 sec timespan.

Answer (score -1):

```
     try{

        // Add your complete portion of code here //

        System.out.println("Portion of code executed Successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception name)
        {
        System.out.println("Portion of code failed");   
        }
```

Please try and let me know.......

Comment: If element not found then no exception is handling, always time out error after few minutes.