# Selenium : Does a WebElement has children or not?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I know if a WebElement has childs or not?

Specifically, I have the following element:

[image]

The capabilities element, sometimes has span elements inside it and sometimes doesn't

I need the ones that has span childs.

How can I get them?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You have to find and count elements inside the td element.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `try/except`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="capabilities"]/span')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("There are no child 'span' elements")
```

Comment: Agreed. Use try, for if there are no spans, a NoSuchElementException is likely to be thrown by findElements().

Answer (score 0):

I must say that I had a bug in my code which caused me think I don't know the answer, but for everyone who might be interested, I used this:

```
List spans = capab.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
```

and then just checked

```
spans.size().
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it (using has reference [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present):

```
try{
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='capabilities']/span");
     System.out.println("There is span!");
     return true;
catch(NoSuchElementException e){
     System.out.println("No span!");
     return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expound on @dushkin  answer, we use `findElements` because its exception-safe :

```
By locator = By.xpath(".//td/span");
List<WebElement> subElements = capab.findElements(locator);
```

and then just checked

```
boolean hasSubElements = (subElements.size() > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the inner child of web element through HTML dom manipulation, run the following command in your js file on documents load:

> console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('capabilities'))

This will give you an array of html elements the class belongs to, iterate over each index and check if the innerHTML or children have span tag in it.