# Selenium for each loop error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My for each loop gives me an error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"invite_someone_failure"} 
I only want the loop to restart if its been displayed and then check for invite_someone_success but it has not been displayed yet and stops before it can restart loop. Also doesn't seem to refresh the page

```
                foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\\extract\\in7.txt"))
            {
                if (line.Contains("@"))
                {
                    searchEmail.SendKeys(line);
                    submitButton.Click();
                    var result = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("invite_someone_success")).Text;
                    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("C:\\extract\\out7.txt"))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(result + ":" + line);
                    }
                    var unfollowButton = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("unfollow_button"));
                    unfollowButton.Click();

                    if (driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("invite_someone_failure")).Displayed) {
                    driver.Navigate().Refresh();

                    }
                }
```

Comment: It's throwing that exception because you're attempting to find that element in your if statement.  You need to try to find the element and then catch the exception or else it will stop execution.

Comment: You should check first if the element exists. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present) you may find how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because Selenium can't find any element with the class `invite_someone_failure`.

When it can't find an element it throws an exception thus aborting the loop. This also explains why your page isn't refreshed as the code to refresh the page is after the exception happens.

Since you have an `if` statement I can guess you don't want an exception in `driver.FindElement` to abort your execution.

Try something like this:

```
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("invite_someone_failure"));

if (elements.Any())
    driver.Navigate().Refresh();
```