# Selenium Fast Way To Find If Element Exists

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium to do some searching and testing on a web page. On this page there is a large number of elements that may or may not exist. Most of the time they do not exist but it is critical to find them when they do. I've used

```
WebElement.findElement(By);
WebElement.findElements(By);
WebDriver.findElement(By);
WebDriver.findElements(By);
```

All of these methods are very time consuming when they don't find any elements that match the By parameter. Is there a faster way? At this point I'm considering multithreading just for the elements that may or may not exist but that's a whole other can of worms I'd rather not open.

The linked duplicate question does not address the main issue of my question. That main issue being the time it takes for findElement and findElements to return when they don't find any elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver - Test if element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present)

Comment: Do you have an implicit wait in the code?

Comment: I do. I'm not a smart person sometimes. It's set to ten seconds. That'd resolve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this raises a second question. Is there a way to remove the implicit wait entirely?

Comment: Yes, remove all references to implicit wait and when you need a wait, add `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: If you already have a working test automation be carefully removing all implicit waits, as it may cause other issues of elements not being found. For calls where you want to remove implicit wait set it to 0 and after making those calls switch it back. Otherwise explicit wait is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Let me address your questions individually :

- `Large number of elements that may or may not exist` : We souldn't search for elements which doesn't exist. Rather if the element is **`not_visible`** we should try to bring the element within the [**`View Port`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) to interact with it.
- `methods are very time consuming` : **`findElement`** and **`findElements`** are based on same **`Algorithm`**. So functionally both have similar kind of performance. So to interact with those elements better we need to construct unique **`css`** or **`xpath`** along with a matching clause for **`ExpectedCondition`**
- `WebDriver.findElement(By)` and `WebElement.findElement(By)` : As **`WebElement.findElement(By)`** always carry the base reference of the **`WebDriver`** instance, most possibly **`WebDriver.findElement(By);`** will always have an edge with respect to performance.