# vb.net Selenium How to implement 'if webelement exists then do some stuff'?

Tags: vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried these(in scenario when the element does not exist) and always getting

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException

---

```
If driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='username']")).Displayed = True Then
     driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='username']")).Click()
 End If
```

---

```
  If driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='username']")) = True Then
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='username']")).Click()
```

---

```
    If driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='username']")).Displayed Then
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='username']")).Click()
```

Comment: Use `.FindElements()` and check that the count is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use try catch block to handle this & then execute the action on the element if it isn't null.Something like this :

```
webelement ele = null
try
{
   ele = driver.FindElement("your condition");
}
catch(NoSuchElementException ex)
{
  #do-nothing
}
if(ele != null)
{
   #perform your action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the WebDriver API is the same for VB as it is for Java, you can use the same approach as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9188374/5803406.