# How can i set an error in output when calling FindElement in chromedriver headless mode?

Tags: c#, google-chrome-headless, chrome-web-driver

I am using headless mode with ChromeDriver.
I find an element by calling

```
 var name= Driver.FindElement(By.Id("TestLabelName"));
 if (name== null)
 { 
 }
```

The issue here is that if the element is not present it just exceptions and stops and doesnt do the null check.
Is there a way to return either the element or just null ?
Or return the console window data without having to wrap every FindElement around a try catch ?

Answer (score 0):

Use FindElements instead of FindElement.

findElements will return an empty list if no matching elements are found instead of an exception.

Text copied from: [Test if element is present using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present)

---

Also you can write a static method that looks for an element:

```
    public static IWebElement _FindElement(ChromeDriver inCromeDriver, string inNameElementId)
    {
        try
        {
            var name = inCromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(inNameElementId));
            return name;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there anything similar to Assert.Equal as used in ui tests ?

Comment: @Kristy Yes, you can write a static method that looks for an element, if an exception occurs in this method, then return null

Comment: great thanks.. So i assume if an exception is raised , I can just call Driver.close() to quit the console ? And log errors to a log file ? Is that best practice ?