# Selenium with C#-How to validate that a link is read only for a particular type of user?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I need to validate that a particular login user with read only access rights will not have links enabled for him/her on a webpage. How can selenium verify this behavior since the  tag itself is missing in this case.

I am trying out with this piece of code.

//Verify if the product name is clickable when logged in with read only permission

```
public static bool ProductNameClickable()
{

        try
        {
            WebDriverWait waitForObject = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            waitForObject.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(".//*[@id='resultsTable']/tbody/tr/td/a")));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false, "Product name accessible to unautorized user. Error Details:" + e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element is there or not. If the element is not there then the Privileges is working fine.

Below is the java code. Implement it same as in C#. I believe it do not need more efforts.

```
boolean yes = driver.findElements(By.id("dd") ).size() != 0;

if(yes==false){
    System.out.println("Priviledges is working");
}else{
    System.out.println("Priviledges is not working");
}
  }
```

OR
C#

```
IWebElement myLink = driver.FindElementSafe(By.Id("myId"));
if (myLink.Exists)
{
   Console.Write("Priviledges is working ");
}
else{
       Console.Write("Priviledges is not working ");
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I have added a code for C# .. hope it will help you

Comment: mu c# is not as good .. refer below link if still facing issue :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists

Comment: tried with count() and its working but takes a lot of time to figure out that the given elements do not exist

Comment: just put down your implicit wait down for 5 sec before this code

Comment: What is `FindElementSafe()`?