# How do I determine if a WebElement exists with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I know I could use `(driver.findElements(By.xpath("Xpath Value")).size() != 0);`

However, I am using a Page Object Model, whose entire purpose is to predefine the WebElements in a separate class, so I don't have to "FindElements By" in my test classes.

Here's what I currently have

```
if (objPage.webElement.isEnabled()){
   System.out.println("found element");
}else{
   System.out.println("element not found");
}
```

However, this tries to identify the *possibly* non-existent WebElement. When it is not present, I get:

> No Such Element" exception.

Comment: Try using List<WebElement> when you are using the FindBy annotation for the element which might not exist? If not size will be zero.

Comment: @Grasshopper It's a good answer! Why didn't you make it full-fledged instead of simple comment?

Comment: @Cryptor The answer by JeffC has the same logic and I think is the correct way of handling these cases.

Comment: @Grasshopper Sorry if don't get something but how it can be used in _Page Object_ model where there is no _WebDriver_ element since class is initialized using _PageFactory.initElements()_ method?

Comment: @Cryptor Add a new question.

Comment: Canonical questions are *[Test if an element is present using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/test-if-an-element-is-present-using-selenium-webdriver)* (32 answers. 2011) and *[WebDriver: check if an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists)* (14 answers. 2011).

Comment: Is that the actual message? Not something like "`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best practice is to do what you originally suggested. Use `.findElements()` and check for `.size != 0`, or you can also use my preference, `.isEmpty()`. You can create a utility function like the below to test if an element exists.

```
public boolean elementExists(By locator)
{
    return !driver.findElements(locator).isEmpty();
}
```

You could also build this into a function in your page object.

Answer (score -2):

You can use isDisplayed() to check whether or not an element is visible. It’s trivial enough to write a method which will do what you want. Something like:

```
public boolean isElementDisplayed(WebElement element) {
    try {
        return element.isDisplayed();
    } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A word of warning... this answer has a hidden gotcha. What if you want to confirm that an element is NOT displayed but the element does not exist? This function will return `false` and the test will pass but the element wasn't even on the page... a false positive. Test the element for existence... then test if it is enabled.

Comment: We need to check existence of the element before checking any condition on it.