# JAVA Selenium WebElement overriding click() method

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

Is it good practice to `override WebElement click()` to add some `wait` functionality, because in some pages i need to click button and in some cases button is not loaded yet so i added wait to check if element is visible.

**So My question is:** Is it better to create `abstract class` which would implement WebElement and override click() method to add some wait functionality or it is better just to have plain wait only in specific pages ?

Comment: It is always good to add waits with timeouts. You need them to make your tests more reliable across platforms.

Comment: In some pages, if button is not loaded completely, then you should provide `explicit wait` before going to hit the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the documentation [Document Object Model (DOM) Level 2 HTML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361) `click()` method doesn't *accepts any parameters*, doesn't *return any value* and doesn't *report any exceptions*.

[image]

So, its clear that we can't override `click()` method in the first place.

But you can always write a customized user function to click on a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) along with certain types of waits. In these cases [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s in-built [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) i.e. the [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) comes to our help.

---

### ExplicitWait

As per the [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits), an [ExplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693634/why-do-some-elements-exist-but-not-interactable-displayed/57699893#57699893) is a code block you define, configure and implement for the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance to wait for a certain condition to be met before proceeding for the next line of code.  There are some methods that helps us to implement *ExplicitWait* that will wait only as long as required. *WebDriverWait* in combination with *ExpectedCondition* is one of the way *ExplicitWait* can be achieved.

You can find a detailed discussion on *ExplicitWait* in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way to do it, the problems which may occurs due to wait

> 1- For each click event it will wait for some time.
>
> 2- Whatever wait time you are giving may end before the page loads completely (it will work for some pages and fail for the others)

Instead you find that element first and continue the executions see below questions for more details

[WebDriver: check if an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists)

[Selenium WebDriver - Test if element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do that, as WebElement is an interface not an class (or abstract class).

However if you want, you could implement your own click method which does waiting and then clicking for you.

```
public void waitAndClick(By identifer){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    WebElement elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(identifer));
    elem.click();
}
```