# Why do some elements exist but not interactable/displayed?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm pretty new to testing, trying to gain a better understanding of what exactly is going on.  I'm finding some of our test codes are failing when the css selector element has a waitUntilCanInteract or waitUntilDisplayed attached to it even though when I do a chrome inspect the element is showing up in the browser.  Changing them to a waitUntilExists gets them to a passing point so I was wondering what exactly is going on to create this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Precisesly [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) deals with three unique states of an element.

- *Presence of element* within the [html](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp): This state of an element can be detected through the *ExpectedCondition* [`presenceOfElementLocated()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) where the expectation is to check if the element is **present** in the [DOM](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is *visible*.

  - Exmaple:

    ```
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("css_of_element")));
    ```
- *Visibility of element* within the [html](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp): This state of an element can be detected through the *ExpectedCondition* [`visibilityOfElementLocated()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) where the expectation is to check if the element is **present** in the [DOM](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of a page and **visible**. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a *height* and *width* that is greater than **0**.

  - Exmaple:

    ```
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("css_of_element")));
    ```
- *Element to be clickable*: This state of an element can be detected through the *ExpectedCondition* [`elementToBeClickable()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) where the expectation is to check if the element **visible** and **enabled** so that you can click it.

  - Exmaple:

    ```
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("css_of_element")));
    ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium: Check for the presence of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element/50621712#50621712)

Answer (score -1):

Well, the developers decided to make it so.

See, the elements can exist on the DOM but be invisible or un-interactable. But not the other way around.

If your tests are passing when waitingUntilExists and failing otherwise, you probably have to prolong the waiting period if you want to make them pass. But this is just my guesswork without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Ah ok this makes sense.  Yeah I'm sure it's difficult to go too into detail without seeing it, I more so wanted to get a general idea of why, which this response was helpful.  If it helps any further, one instance this happened was on a mini card that popped up when mouse hovered.  This element was only clickable with javascript code, but again resulted as false when asked if the element was displayed(even though the mouse was hovered over and I could see the element in the chrome tools), but resulted as true for if it existed.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is that sometimes when designer work on web pages especially while working on Foundation CSS framework or bootstrap, they intentionally hide the original CSS/HTML tags and elements while placing foundation or bootstrap based design overlays like fancy buttons on the page which causes the original elements to be hidden.

The best approach may be like:

I. You can declare a WebElement while calling an element to precisely targeting it and using moveToElement command instead of simply calling FindElement.By.xxxxx
ex:

```
//*** Calling a WebElement and using moveToElement command***//

WebElement (anyElementname) = browser.findElement(By.partialLinkText("xxxxxxxxxxx"));
          action.moveToElement(anyElementname).perform();
//*** Waiting for 8 seconds***//          
Thread.sleep(8000, 80000);
```

II. You can use 'waits' for providing page load time and interacting between elements

III. Avoid copying the overlayed css elemenet especially xpath, instead, copy the xpath from the original source of the Div/button/li

Let me know if it works for you or not. Cheers!