# How to automate the clicking of the navigation menu avoiding NoSuchElementException in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have implemented a `Selenium Java` program where I need to automate the clicking of the navigation menu. Below is the implementation of my code.

**NewCard.java**

```
public class NewCard {
public static void createTopUpRequestNewCard(WebDriver driver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement utilitytopup = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='wrapper']/div/ul/li[9]/a")));
    utilitytopup.click();
    WebElement createtopupnewcard = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'create top up request (new card)')]")));
    createtopupnewcard.click();
}
}
```

**Utility Top Up Menu**

```
<a href="#" class="menu__link"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-inline--fa fa-user fa-w-14 menu__icon" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="user" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 256c70.7 0 128-57.3 128-128S294.7 0 224 0 96 57.3 96 128s57.3 128 128 128zm89.6 32h-16.7c-22.2 10.2-46.9 16-72.9 16s-50.6-5.8-72.9-16h-16.7C60.2 288 0 348.2 0 422.4V464c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-41.6c0-74.2-60.2-134.4-134.4-134.4z"></path></svg><!-- <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-user menu__icon"></i> --> Utility Top Up <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-inline--fa fa-chevron-right fa-w-10 menu__arrow-icon" focusable="false" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="chevron-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M285.476 272.971L91.132 467.314c-9.373 9.373-24.569 9.373-33.941 0l-22.667-22.667c-9.357-9.357-9.375-24.522-.04-33.901L188.505 256 34.484 101.255c-9.335-9.379-9.317-24.544.04-33.901l22.667-22.667c9.373-9.373 24.569-9.373 33.941 0L285.475 239.03c9.373 9.372 9.373 24.568.001 33.941z"></path></svg><!-- <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-right menu__arrow-icon"></i> --></a>
```

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

**Create Top Up New Card(Sub-Section)**

```
<a href="#" class="context-menu__link"> create top up request (new card) </a>
```

**Screenshot2**

[image]

I have attempted putting in `CssSelector`, `Linktext`, and `XPath` but to no avail. On top of that, I have used `Selenium IDE` to record it and the screenshots above are the 2 elements I'm handling respectively. Nevertheless, despite trying these locators I'm still getting `NoSuchElementException`.

May I know how to solve this?

Comment: Is it possible, that the element is not fully loaded yet, when the click happens?

Comment: I have tried Explicit Wait. But to no avail

Comment: Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Shotokan potentially might be the cause of it. I have tried putting wait but to no avail too

Comment: Can you try to give the HTML elements IDs and then try to use the method `getElementByID()`? Just to see if the XPath is the problem.

Comment: there's no id. Everytime I use Selenium IDE to record and play my test. There are unique ids generated for the same web element

Comment: On topof that, it's built on top of Vue JS framework

Comment: Ok... Because it't difficult for me to tell if the XPath you are using is correct, because you only provided the HTML of the 2 links, but what I see from the XPaths is that there must be more HTML content around them.

Comment: For the second link I would for example use this XPath: `//a[text()='create top up request (new card)']`. For the second one I don't know because I don't have the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) of [`visibilityOfElementLocated()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) doesn't ensures that the element is **interactable**. Instead you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element/50621712#50621712) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693634/why-do-some-elements-exist-but-not-interactable-displayed/57699893#57699893) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
public class NewCard {
    public static void createTopUpRequestNewCard(WebDriver driver) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='menu__link' and contains(., 'Utility Top Up')]"))).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='menu__link' and contains(., 'create top up request')]"))).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: I seriously don't know what to do with this