# Getting ElementNotInteractableException for sendKeys statement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Tried executing the code but getting:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

for the below sendKeys statement. What could be the solution??

```
WebElement ss = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='select__single-value css-1uccc91-singleValue']"));
ss.click();
ss.sendKeys("abc");
```

Comment: use sendkeys to input element not div

Comment: I have used sendkeys only as you can see in the last statement.That is where I am facing the error

Comment: @use it on <input> not <div>

Comment: dine element that starts wit h<input>

Answer (score 0):

Generally `<div>` tags are not [interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693634/why-do-some-elements-exist-but-not-interactable-displayed/57699893#57699893) unless [contenteditable="true"] ([How to modify the innerHTML of a contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914416/how-to-modify-the-innerhtml-of-a-contenteditable-element/52917565#52917565)) is attribute is explicitly set.

---

### Solution

If your usecase is to invoke `click()` / `sendKeys()` generally you have to invoke on `<input>` elements but not on `<div>`. Try to identify the element using the [inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-for-selenium-v3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-fo/46702281#46702281) opening the [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) and identify the desired `<input>` element.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion on [ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by/49872160#49872160) in:

- [Selenium WebDriver throws Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690971/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-element/44691041#44691041)
- [How to resolve ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible in Selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni/46601444#46601444)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the correct path as div tags are usually not interactable.

```
By.cssSelector("div[class='select__single-value css-1uccc91-singleValue']");
```

Here, you are using the compound class which is no longer allowed in selenium.
So, try using:

```
By.cssSelector("div[class='.select__single-value.css-1uccc91-singleValue']");
```