# selenium how to know if one element has a href link or not,if not continue the test

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium java 3.141.59 and testng 6.14.3.
The test page may display like

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="S_line1">
      <strong class="W_f12">82</strong>
      <span class="S_txt2">fans</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

or

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="S_line1">
      <a bpfilter="page_frame" class="t_link S_txt1" href="//xx.com/p/1003061291477752/follow?from=page_100306&amp;wvr=6&amp;mod=headfollow#place">
        <strong class="W_f12">170</strong>
        <span class="S_txt2">fans</span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

If "fans" have a href link,then I will click "fans" link. If not I will skip this step and continue to do others. 
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated is not availabe to this situation, because it will throw exeception when not finding href link and stop the test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriver: check if an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists)

Comment: @Sers this is a bit different... OP is looking for an element with `href`, not the classic "check if an element exists"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For checking the node `href` is present or not, you can use the below XPath to identify the `a` node because `href` is present inside of `a`(I'm assuming that the class is unique here, if not then use some other locator with `//a` appending at the end) :

```
String xpath = "//td[@class=\"S_line1\"]/a"
```

You can check for it's presence like below :

```
List<WebElement> hrefs = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
if(hrefs.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("=> The href is present...");
    hrefs.get(0).click();
} else {
    System.out.println("=> The href is not present...");
}
```

The above code will not throw any error if the `href` is not there. So you don't need to handle any exceptions there.

I hope it helps...

Comment: this is a good approach too... see my answer which will find only the linkText of `fans`... what do you think?

Comment: Yes @Moshe Slavin, but it will throw an error if the expected value is not present and you are wrapping it with `try-catch` block which is known option so I have tried differently - Your's is still good approach...

Answer (score 1):

Following code first finds all the `<a>` tags within the table, and one by one if  tag have `href`, will click them:

```
List<WebElement> allAnchorElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//td[@class='S_line1']/a"));

for(WebElement currElem : allAnchorElements ){

     if(currElem.getAttribute("href")){

           currElem.click();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for only the `fans` element that has the `href`...

The best way I can think of is to use [`By.linkText()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#linkText-java.lang.String-).

In your case:

```
try{
    WebElement link  = driver.findElement(By.linkText("fans"));
    System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
    link.click();
    }
catch(NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Hope this helps you!