# How can i get only name and contact number?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get name and contact number from div. div sometimes has one span, sometimes two, and sometimes three. My expectation is that:

- I only need name and contact number if available
- In some cases, name will not be available and contact number will be available, then name variable should be assigned 'N/A'
- In some cases, contact number will not be available and name will be available, then variable should be assigned 'N/A'

This is what I have so far:

```
// if you change url to url-1 and url-2 then you will see how it works.
url = "https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/19442-185th-Ave-SE-Renton-WA- 
98058/54831221_zpid/"
#url-1 = "https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/20713-61st-St-E-Bonney-Lake-WA-98391/99371104_zpid/"
#url-2 = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/fsbo/house_type/121319389_zpid/globalrelevanceex_sort/47.465758,-122.259207,47.404798,-122.398424_rect/12_zm/5f9305c92cX1-CRbri51bo8epha_yly1g_crid/0_mmm/"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')

contacts = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.listing-field")
contact_name = []
contact_phone = "N/A"
contact_web = "N/A"

for i in range(0, len(contacts)):
    if len(contacts[i].find_elements_by_tag_name("a")) > 0:
    contact_web = 
    contacts[i].find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
    elif re.search("\\(\\d+\\)\\s+\\d+-\\d+", contacts[i].text):
        contact_phone = contacts[i].text
    else:
        contact_name.append(contacts[i].text)

print(contact_phone) // Output: (253) 335-8690
print(contact_name)  // Output: ['Sheetal Datta']
```

Comment: what's wrong w/this code?

Comment: Now name are storing in a list, i want name in a variable and if either name or contact_number is not found then variable should be assigned as N/A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You should approach this problem in a programmatic way, namely with conditions. As you already noted,

```
if the name exists and the contact number exists,
    use them
else if the name exists only,
    use the name and assign the contact number as 'N/A'
else if the contact number exists only,
    use the contact number and assign the name as 'N/A'
```

As you can see, you can implement the above pseudo-code as actual conditional statements in Python using if-elif-else statements. Depending on how the webpage is structured, you'll want to check for the existence of the `span`'s first before you try to read values from them, which you can do following this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try: except:` to check if contact name and phone number present or not and then assign value accordingly. See the code...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = ('https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/19442-185th-Ave-SE-Renton-WA-'
'98058/54831221_zpid/')

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')
browser.quit()
tag = soup.find('div',attrs={
    'class':'home-details-listing-provided-by zsg-content-section'})

try:
    contact_name = tag.find('span',attrs={
        'class':'listing-field'}).text
except:
    contact_name = 'N/A'

try:
    contact_phone = tag.find('span',attrs={
        'class':'listing-field'}).findNext('span').text
except:
    contact_phone = 'N/A'


print('Contact Name: {}\nContact Phone: {}'.format(
    contact_name,contact_phone))
```

Output:

```
Contact Name: Sheetal Datta
Contact Phone: (253) 335-8690
```