# Is there a way to catch selenium exception in a java function from tests

Tags: java, selenium

Assert an element is not displayed throws and exception that is not catch in the caller block

I use this function from webdriverextensions for verify an element is not displayed `assertIsNotDisplayed(driver().findElement ....)`

The problem here is if the method do not finds the element, throws a NoSuchElementException that is ignoring the catch block.

```
public static boolean isDisplayed(WebElement webElement) {
  try {
    return webElement.isDisplayed();
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return false;
  }
}

public static void assertIsNotDisplayed(WebElement webElement) {
  try {
    if (isDisplayed(webElement)) {
      throw new WebAssertionError(
        "Element is displayed when it shouldn't", webElement);
    }
  } catch (final NoSuchElementException |
       java.util.NoSuchElementException | 
   org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException ignore) {}
}
```

On use this method on the test I get a NoSuchElementException but I was expecting the catch block to work.

What Im missing on java error handling ?

Comment: Can you share your test case code?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists