# Login process : Not read my else statement in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

My `if else` inside my for loop. This `if else` to verify the data from the `excel` to login. I try to bug, it shows that it skip `else` statement.

Getting error :

```
no such element " email".
```

The error at line: `driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();`

```
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) { 
                        cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
                        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
                        email.sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());                      

                        cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
                        WebElement password = driver.findElement (By.name("password"));
                        password.sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());


                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]")).click();
                        Thread.sleep(8000);

                        try {

                            if(driver.findElement(By.className("description")).isDisplayed()) {
                                System.out.println("invalid");
                                driver.findElement(By.id("btn-skip")).click();

                                }
                                else{
                                        System.out.println("invalid");
                                        //driver.findElement(By.id("btn-skip")).click();
                                }

                        }
                        catch(NoSuchElementException e) {

                        }

                        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();

                        System.out.print(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0) + " ");
                        System.out.println(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1));

                        }
```

Comment: If it doesn't go into your `else` statement, that means that your conditional holds true.

Comment: i got three data. 2 of it is wrong.it should go to else  condition

Comment: This is error appear when you put correct credential ?

Comment: when i put wrong credential. it suppose to print "invalid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if to [check size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists) to avoid exception

```
  driver.findElements( By.className("description") ).size() != 0
```

Comment: @samazlan see differences https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/difference-between-findelement-and-findelements-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether there aren't more elements with the same class name *'Description'*. If there are, you could use CssSelector to narrow it down to the one you want.